# What is the opposite of a invariant set in dynamical systems?

Tags: definition, dynamical-systems

I am studying a dynamical system, and I have found set in phase phase such that any solution that enters the set must exit it. This to me would be the opposite of an invariant set.

My question is whether there is a formal definition for a non-invariant set?

Comment: Transient set perhaps?

Comment: [Wandering set](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Wandering_set) is also somewhat related.